# AMD Graphics Driver Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon

I have installed Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 on my laptop which has a Radeon R5 M255 GPU. How can I install drivers for it? On amd website there are only for ubuntu 14.04. I just want to install them without having problems like black screen after booting.

```
  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2248
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
0a:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz PRO [Radeon R5 M255]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 224a
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|Display' -A2` terminal command. And do not download drivers from sites.

Comment: Why should OP "not download drivers from sites"? AMD's website should have working and trustworthy AMD drivers, if anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drivers can be installed from

System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers

Do not download any video drivers from sites. It may result in black screen after reboot or a kernel upgrade.

Ubuntu way is to install from repositories.

Comment: But what if I have nothing to choose from in Additional drivers? How should I make the drivers appear there?

Answer (score 0):

fglrx should solve the problem

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates-core fglrx-updates
```

Comment: The proprietary fglrx drivers worked for me in with 14.04, but I couldn't remember how I'd installed them. I'm upgrading to 15.04 now, so I'll be back to upvote if this still works. Thanks.